# How to solve PHP Extensions “0” must be loaded?

Tags: magento, web

I am trying to install Magento on my server. I did everything, as written in docs. I have following error:

> PHP Extensions “0” must be loaded

It occurs when I try to configure Magento in my browser, on the second page. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check all the requirements? PHP version, MySQL version required by the Magento version you are trying to install?

Comment: Yes, everything as written in docs. All extensions, versions, etc.

Comment: Are you working locally or on a remote server?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are installing Magento version 1.7.0.1, try the following to solve your issue:

Replace in file `app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml` (near 71th string):

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql/>
</extensions>
```

with this

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql>1</pdo_mysql>
</extensions>
```

Comment: had to restart apache and this helped

Comment: Though this method works (I just tested on a clean 1.6.2.0 install), I think we can all agree that it isn't considered best practice. Magento provides patches to correct this problem. I just applied the patch suggested in Matthias Kleine's answer below and it correctly resolved the issue.

Comment: You should apply the official PHP 5.4 patch instead of hacking the core manually.

Comment: its not hacking @MatthiasKleine, if some one doesn't able to update their version due to some dependency then it will be help full.

Comment: Sure, but the official PHP 5.4 patch fixes some additional issues with that version you may encounter when fixing this manually.

Answer (score 6):

You have to install the PHP 5.4 support package:

"PHP 5.4 support - Enables Magento to work with PHP 5.4 - Added Jan 17, 2014"
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Definitely the preferred way to do it. Thanks.