# How to avoid "PHP Extensions “0” must be loaded" errror on magento installation?

Tags: php, magento, mozilla

Hi all I am installing the magento 1.7.0.2 in ubuntu 12.04 on the xampp 1.8.3-2 and on the next page on installation it gives an error that

`PHP Extensions “0” must be loaded`

I followed the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800147/how-to-solve-php-extensions-0-must-be-loaded) which returns another error displaying a message window saying

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I tried clearing the cache but it didn't do anything still the problem occurs.

What should I do now. Any help will be greatfull.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am using Xampp 1.8.3-2 and it includes PHP 5.5.6

Comment: Just check whether cookies are enabled or not in your browser

Comment: I already cleared all the cache and cookies but didn't work.

Comment: I am not saying to clear the cache, just check whether your browser can accept the cookie or not, check this http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-enable-cookies-on-my-computer

Comment: yes my browser can accept the cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento currently doesn't support any version of PHP 5.5.  You'll need to run either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 to use Magento.  If you run PHP 5.4, be sure to [apply the recent patch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/magento-now-supports-php-54/), or use the upcoming-when-this-was-written Magento 1.8.2+

Comment: But I am already running my magento site on this version of php, although I created that site in php 5.3 but when I migrate that site in this version it is working fine, except that it is loading the css from the base theme instead of my custom theme.

Comment: Alam ,can you please tell where i will put this this path. i have using magento 1.7.0.2